# Detect my RAM (and maybe tell me where to buy more?)

Tags: windows, gratis, hardware, diagnostics

I am looking for a gratis Windows 10 app to detect my RAM.

I am a software guy, and not really hardware. I know just about enough to know that I want it all to be DDR2/3/4 as appropriate for my motherboard. I would prefer to have it all from the same manufacturer.

For laptops, I get confused by the L suffix (low voltage?) and whether I must use it exclusively/can mix it with similar which is non-L. I also see some with a U suffix.

I am not asking you to explain it to me. I am one of those people who are [happy just to use cotton](http://www.comedyquotes.tv/blackadder-iii-episode-5-amy-amiability-script/), I mean RAM, without having to understand how it works.

I am looking for a gratis Windows 10 program which will examine my system and tell me what kind of RAM I need to buy, ***AND*** makes sure that I do not buy the wrong stuff.

Then I can look on Amazon or eBay and buy some, although it would be a bonus if the app could find a good deal, based on my  country (remembering that we don't all live in the USA)

Comment: I assume that you already did some google like "how to check ram type" or "show ram on windows 10". I found e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/606318/how-to-find-the-ram-type-in-command-prompt and here I saw something about CPU-Z (I used it in the past as well) and "wmic memorychip list full"

Comment: Yes, I did. But I want an app to do it and make sure that I don't make any mistakes. I did try CPU-Z (+1), but it doesn't give me the manufacturer.

Comment: Not an app either but: `wmic MEMORYCHIP get BankLabel,DeviceLocator,Capacity,Speed,Manufacturer` will give you the Manufacturer, see also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for some background information.

Comment: Very useful to know (+1). Does it give me enough info to buy & not buy the wrong thing?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know.

Comment: For instance, that give me speed of 1600, but does not tell me that I need DDR3. It well be that that can be inferred form the speed, but I don't know that & want to the app to tell me.

Comment: I just use Crucial’s RAM selection tool. http://www.crucial.com/

Comment: Which tool? Do you have a URL?

Answer (score 2):

As I already mentioned in the comments:

- a useful link: https://superuser.com/questions/606318/how-to-find-the-ram-type-in-command-prompt
- command line:

  - `wmic memorychip list full`
  - `wmic MEMORYCHIP get BankLabel,DeviceLocator,Capacity,Speed,Manufacturer`
- some explanation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Be sure that you always combine memory with the same speed, for other requirements check with your hardware dealer or check https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The second query gives me `Description = Invalid query`. The first seems alot more useful, ***but**** as someone harwarephobic, I don;t know what is important and what not I suppose I could just email it all off to some seller & trust them to tell me what I need

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, [CPU-Z](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) is a tool that does what you want, even if you have already tried. Maybe you were not too successful, because you looked at the wrong tab.

The type of RAM (like DDR4) is listed in the memory tab.

[image: Screenshot CPU-Z memory tab]

> I am not asking you to explain it to me.

Even if you're not asking, maybe explaining is the key here.

The manufacturer is listed in the SPD tab. Be sure to switch through the different memory slots since a) the tab might be empty in case that slot is empty and b) each module may be from a different manufacturer.

[image: Screenshot of an empty slot]

[image: Screenshot CPU-Z SPD tab]

Note that you'll hardly fine the exact same model (same part number) again. But choosing the same manufacturer is probably a good idea.